# ¿como muestro solo los registros activados en angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

Buenas tardes me pueden ayudar, necesito solo mostrar los **registros activados en angular** de una de las una tablas.

Es decir que me muestre solo cuando estén activados y en el caso que no lo estén que no aparezcan, puesto que ese campo es para un eliminación lógica de los registros.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Listar Formulario</h3>
    </div>
    <p-table [columns]="columnas" [value]="formularios" selectionMode="single"
        [(selection)]="formularioSeleccionado" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [paginator]="true" [rows]="15">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
            Lista de formularios
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                    {{col.header}}
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort"
                        ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order"
                        ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="summary" let-rowData>
            <div style="text-align:left">
                <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-plus" routerLink="../agregarFormulario"
                    class="btn btn-primary active" style="margin-left: 10px" role="button" routerLinkActive="active"
                    label="Nuevo Formulario"></button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

[image: lista de una tabla]

Comment: puedes utilizar **ngIf** para no mostrar registros

Comment: Estas utilizando primeNg ?

Comment: Me podes decir si la variable "columns" la cual recorres con un ngFor , es cargada a partir de un Observable?

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Si esto utilizando en las tablas PrimeNG, el ngIf deberia ir en la parte del html como comparaciones?

Comment: @FrancoGallo esta cargado con un subscribe
básicamente el código es: 
**codigo** 
 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getFormulario().subscribe(resp => {
      this.formularios = resp;
    });
    this.columnas = [
      { field: 'formulario_Id', header: 'Codigo' },
      { field: 'formulario_Titulo', header: 'Titulo' },
      { field: 'formulario_Descripcion', header: 'Descripcion' },
      { field: 'formulario_Fecha', header: 'Fecha' },
      { field: 'formulario_Estado', header: 'Estado' },
    ];
  }

Comment: Antes que nada te pido que el comentario con código que con la respuesta que me diste lo agregues en la pregunta principal asi todos los usuarios pueden verlo claramente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que los datos provenientes del array, *el cual estas mostrando en la vista con **ngFor***, provienen del resultado de un flujo de datos `Observable`, lo mas simple sería hacer uso de la función `filter()` de RxJs antes de suscribirse.

*¿Como quedaría el código?*

```
this.service.getFormulario().pipe(
        filter(value => value.estado != 'activado')
    ).subscribe(resp => { this.formularios = resp; 
    });
```

Vale aclarar que aqui estoy asumiendo que el estado es de tipo string, pero si lo tienes como booleano o int seria reemplazar el `!= 'activado'` por `!= 1` o similar.